# opnecl dot product. Here i am trying to store the result in local variable which resets to zero every time

Tags: synchronization, opencl

my kernel code.

```
__kernel void OUT__1__1527__(__constant float *A,__constant float *B,__global float *res)
 {
  int i = get_global_id(0);
  float C=0;
  if (i <= 5 - 1) {
  C += (A[i] * B[i]);
  *res=C;
 }
}
```

A & B have value {1,2,3,4,5} both.
for this kernel i am getting the result 25 which is 5*5 where as i want the result to be 55. (1*1+2*2+3*3+4*4+5*5)

what code needs to be inserted for synchronization and where does the code need to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic fix for these things. This is a typical reduction problem (where you want to merge multiple results in a single variable).

You can use atomics (but not with float values) if this is not the bottleneck of your algorithm (ie: you are doing other more expensive process elsewhere in the kernel). But if this IS the core of the kernel. Then you should move to change your algorithm completely.

You can start by reading this: http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/

Also your code is wrong, it never actually "merge"s any the data in `res`. it only sets `res` to the value of `C`. And `C` is private to each thread, therefore, it does not sum anything in there. Only the last thread actually wins the datarace, leading to the answer being 25.

There is a trick that **I do NOT recommend** in order to use atomics in floats, based on unions and read/write multiple times to global memory:

```
inline void AtomicAdd(volatile __global float *source, const float operand) {
    union {
        unsigned int intVal;
        float floatVal;
    } newVal;
    union {
        unsigned int intVal;
        float floatVal;
    } prevVal;
    do {
        prevVal.floatVal = *source;
        newVal.floatVal = prevVal.floatVal + operand;
    } while (atomic_cmpxchg((volatile __global unsigned int *)source, prevVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) != prevVal.intVal);
}

__kernel void OUT__1__1527__(__constant float *A,__constant float *B,__global float *res)
 {
  int i = get_global_id(0);
  if (i <= 5 - 1) {
    AtomicAdd(res, (A[i] * B[i]));
 }
}
```

Comment: well i will surely go through it . Thanks for the help